# Can't changing the value of JavaScript property

Tags: javascript, class, object, oop

```js
class Snake {
    snakeDirection = 'ArrowRight';

    constructor() {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.moveSnake();
        }, 800);

        document.addEventListener('keydown', this.changeDirection);
    }

    moveSnake() {
        console.log('moveSnake', this.snakeDirection) //ArrowRight
    }

    changeDirection(e) {
        this.snakeDirection = e.key;
        console.log('key pressed', e.key)
    }
}

let a = new Snake();
```

I'm new to javscript and creating a small project using OOPs concept. I am trying to change the value of snakeDirection by calling changeDirection method but it's can't get updated in moveSnake method which is gets called every 800ms.
How will I do this?

```
class Snake {
    snakeDirection = 'ArrowRight';

    constructor() {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.moveSnake();
        }, 800);

        document.addEventListener('keydown', this.changeDirection);
    }

    moveSnake() {
        console.log('moveSnake', this.snakeDirection) //ArrowRight
    }

    changeDirection(e) {
        this.snakeDirection = e.key;
        console.log('key pressed', e.key)
    }
}

let a = new Snake();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass an argument (event) to func.

```
const snake = new Snake();
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => snake.changeDirection(e));
```

Comment: but why the old method didn't work and this did?

Comment: Because your methods use event from argument. That's why we passing event in callback function.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem that I have spotted `this.snakeDirection` cant be used because it is not in the constructor method. use just `snakeDirection = e.key`.
I mean that it is not the property of the class, it is just a class variable that can't be used as a class property. Class variables and class properties are two different concepts.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's a context issue with `setInterval`. If you change your methods to class properties (basically arrow functions) so that `this` is understood properly the problem disappears.

```js
class Snake {

  snakeDirection = 'ArrowRight';
  
  constructor() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', this.changeDirection);
    setInterval(this.moveSnake, 800);
  }
  
  moveSnake = () => {
    console.log('moveSnake', this.snakeDirection);
  }

  changeDirection = (e) => {
    console.log(e.key)
    this.snakeDirection = e.key;
  }

}

let a = new Snake();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is 'this' in function changeDidrection that not is Object a. it is Object document.
so,Either listener set out of class

```
class Snake {
            
        
            constructor() {
                setInterval(() => {
                    this.moveSnake();
                }, 800);
                this.snakeDirection = 'ArrowRight';
                document.addEventListener('keydown', changeDirection);
            }
        
            moveSnake() {
                console.log('moveSnake', this.snakeDirection) //ArrowRight
            }
            
        }
        
        let a = new Snake();
        function changeDirection(e) {
            a.snakeDirection = e.key;
            console.log('key pressed', e.key)
        }
```

or use arrow function

```
changeDirection = (e) => {
            console.log(e.key)
            this.snakeDirection = e.key;
          }
```